# "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)" occuring in valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

No matter what the program is, valgrind gives nearly the same output :

> Illegal Instruction (core dumped).

Even in this underlying program it shows the same

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int *i)
{
    printf(" %d \n",*i);
}

int main()
{
    int j=90;
    fun(&j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Perhaps, your valgrind is broken?

Comment: install valgrind from the package manager

Answer (score 7):

Your `valgrind` is broken, or is not compatible with your C library.

To confirm this, first see if you can run the `valgrind` binary at all:

```
valgrind --help
```

(if that fails, maybe the binary is corrupt or is for a different architecture)

Then try within something you didn't write:

```
valgrind /bin/true
```

(if that fails, perhaps it's not compatible with your C library)

Assuming one or more of those fails, you will need to reinstall `valgrind` and try again.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'll look forward to this solution.

Comment: I am running into the same problem, yet I am able to run `valgrind /bin/true` fine. Any ideas?